# Log free and top

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I want to create a bash on my server to log a part of the output of "free" and "top" every 60 seconds. I know how to setup the cron job but have no idea how to get the output of "free" and "top" and parse them and save in a file (appending it).

For example, when I run "top" I would like to save only the part as this:

%Cpu(s): 18.2 us,

And when I run "free" I want only to save the "available" column of the first line (Mem:).

So how do I do that bash in centos 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
top -n 1 | awk '/^%Cpu\(s\)/ {print "%Cpu(s)", $2, "us"}'
free | awk '/^Mem:/ {print $7}'
```

Comment: Hi, I executed your code and it always shows the same CPU values, always. Do you have any idea why? By the way it's a good code, thank you so much. I just need to solve why the output of your code always shows the same %

Comment: Because `top` hasn't had time to sample cpu usage properly. It's not until the second iteration that it has useful values.

Comment: `top -bn 2 -d 1 | awk '/^%Cpu/ {v=$2} END{ print v }'`

Answer (score 1):

I you want to monitor every 1 minute, I would recommend using the load average of the CPU instead of the current usage.

`cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print "Load last minute:", $1}'`

This line will give you the average CPU usage in the last minute, which is more accurate than the %CPU used because you may have a peak of 100% and save that even if your average utilization is much less.